# Initiate save dialog for image link

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I was surprised that there is no straightforward solution to this problem. Nothing I found on the web or on SO seems to work.

For example I have this html code:

```
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
```

I want to evoke save as dialog when user clicks on this image, instead opening the image in new window, as it's a format understood by browser. There must be at least some javascript to do the task, or?

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely cannot do it on client side, neither in HTML, nor Javascript, it can only be done by sending the correct HTTP response headers from server side.

Comment: Thanks, but that would be terrible... Weren't there gallery templates with such feature? I'll try a bit harder, but I hope it's not impossible.